# Akeneo Connector Job Code not found

Tags: magento2.4.3

I've installed the Akeneo connector on 2 instances, one instance is an existing Magento installation 2.4.3-p1 with existing products and extensions. The second instance is a new installation without any content. The second installation works perfectly. In the first installation I can not perform any jobs.

All configurable options for the connector are the same on both installations.

```
php bin/magento akeneo_connector:import --code=category
Job code not found
```

```
php bin/magento akeneo_connector:import -v
Options:
--code

Available codes:
```

**Admin panel looks like this:**

[image]

**It should look like this:**

[image]

The database table TABEL: AKENEO_CONNECTOR_JOB is empty

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for your Akeneo connector in other instances. This may be due to other extension issues:

Please follow the steps below to reproduce:

- Check Error Logs if there are any other
- Check the server error and other logs

When most likely Categories are fetched one by one through the Akeneo API. Which, although fast individually, is very slow in large quantities. I would suggest fetching them in batches of 100 and then processing those.

There can be any other extension creating issue in it so please share the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty fix, but I noticed the table AKENEO_CONNECTOR_JOB was empty. I exported the table structure&data from my working instance to my failing instance and this solved the issue.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `akeneo_connector_job`;
CREATE TABLE `akeneo_connector_job` (
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Job ID',
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING' COMMENT 'Status',
  `scheduled_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date scheduled to launch the job',
  `last_executed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last executed date',
  `last_success_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last date the job was executed correctly',
  `job_class` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Job import class',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Job import name',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Job position to priorize launch',
  `last_success_executed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last executed success date',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Akeneo Connector Job';

INSERT INTO `akeneo_connector_job` (`entity_id`, `code`, `status`, `scheduled_at`, `last_executed_date`, `last_success_date`, `job_class`, `name`, `position`, `last_success_executed_date`) VALUES
(1, 'category', '1',    '2023-03-18 14:35:12',  '2023-03-18 14:36:03',  '2023-03-18 14:36:14',  'Akeneo\\Connector\\Job\\Category', 'Category', 0,  '2023-03-18 14:36:03'),
(2, 'family',   '1',    '2023-03-18 15:21:46',  '2023-03-18 15:22:02',  '2023-03-18 15:22:07',  'Akeneo\\Connector\\Job\\Family',   'Family',   1,  '2023-03-18 15:22:02'),
(3, 'attribute',    '1',    '2023-03-18 15:22:58',  '2023-03-18 15:23:02',  '2023-03-18 15:23:07',  'Akeneo\\Connector\\Job\\Attribute',    'Attribute',    2,  '2023-03-18 15:23:02'),
(4, 'option',   '1',    '2023-03-18 15:23:15',  '2023-03-18 15:24:02',  '2023-03-18 15:24:09',  'Akeneo\\Connector\\Job\\Option',   'Option',   3,  '2023-03-18 15:24:02'),
(5, 'product',  '1',    '2023-03-18 15:24:34',  '2023-03-18 15:25:03',  '2023-03-17 02:40:46',  'Akeneo\\Connector\\Job\\Product',  'Product',  4,  '2023-03-16 23:00:04');
```